# JSON error: Compiler Error Message: CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

This is my **controller** class:

```
 public JsonResult FetchGraphDataJSON()
    {
        DataTable dt = FetchFirstDataTable();

        List<GridModel> data = new List<GridModel>();

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                GridModel model = new GridModel();

                model.ID = Convert.ToDouble(row["ID"].ToString());
                model.SHORT_NAME = row["SHORT_NAME"].ToString();
                model.CARRIER_NAME = row["CARRIER_NAME"].ToString();

                model.GridSparklineModel = new List<GridSparklineModel>();

                double carrierId = Convert.ToDouble(row["ID"].ToString());

                DataTable dt2 = GetDt2();

                foreach (DataRow item2 in dt2.Select("ID=" + carrierId))
                {
                    model.GridSparklineModel.Add(new GridSparklineModel { YMDH = DateTime.Parse(item2["YMDH"].ToString()), SELL_DURATION = Convert.ToDouble(item2["SELL_DURATION"]) });
                }

                data.Add(model);
            }
        }

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public DataTable FetchFirstDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("SHORT_NAME");
        dt.Columns.Add("CARRIER_NAME");

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "A", "Carrier A");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "B", "Carrier B");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "C", "Carrier C");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "D", "Carrier D");
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "E", "Carrier E");
        dt.Rows.Add(6, "F", "Carrier F");
        dt.Rows.Add(7, "G", "Carrier G");
        return dt;
    }

    public DataTable GetDt2()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("YMDH");
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("SELL_DURATION");

        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 00:00:00.000", 1, 222.999995);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 01:00:00.000", 1, 75.816664);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 02:00:00.000", 1, 39.349995);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 03:00:00.000", 1, 275.91666);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 04:00:00.000", 1, 352.666641);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 00:00:00.000", 2, 80.783324);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 01:00:00.000", 2, 162.049985);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 02:00:00.000", 2, 107.199989);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 03:00:00.000", 2, 44.849994);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 04:00:00.000", 2, 156.516658);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 05:00:00.000", 2, 467.583312);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 06:00:00.000", 2, 455.199977);

        return dt;
    }
```

cshtml

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var url = '@Url.Action("FetchGraphDataJSON", "Grid")';

        var rawData = null;
        $.ajax({
            // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
            // will return before the data is fetched
            async: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                rawData = data;
            }
        });


        var plotData = []

        for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
            //Parse the date.
            document.write(rawData[i] + "<br>");
        }

    });
</script>
```

While running this it gives error: Compiler Error Message: CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile. Any idea how to resolve this. I am using vs2012 with mvc and c#.

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: Don't use `async: false`; it will freeze the browser.  Instead, you need to learn to write async code.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`; instead, use jQuery to modify the DOM.

Comment: Why are you using AJAX at all? You should write out the data directly on the server.

Comment: Thanks SLaks for the replies. I see this error when I run the website in browser. Can you please suggest how can I get the JSON from the controller class here in cshtml. This works in my other projects but not working here so either there is something wrong in controller class or the way I am trying to fetch data in cshtml. Please advise.

Comment: Just pass that data in the model from your original action.